# Import sheet data into an include file using Google Apps Scriptlets in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have a layout created with HtmlService of Google Apps Script (see masterPage.html, below).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <? var serverData = getServerData(); ?>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Page begin.</h2>
  <p>Data A from server: <?= serverData[0] ?></p>
  <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('includedPage').getContent(); ?>
  <p>Page end.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This layout calls HTML from a second layout called includedPage.html.

```
<? var serverData = getServerData(); ?>
<div>
  <p>Data B from server: <?= serverData[1] ?></p>
</div>
```

I can use a G.A.S. [scriptlet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets) to get data (**"Data A from server"**) from the server/sheet and into the master page.

However, the same scriptlet does not work when placed in the included page. The code simply renders as HTML and **"Data B from server"** is not displayed.

Is there a way to import server/sheet into the include page before the include page gets inserted into the master page?

Any assistance appreciated.

Note: the following questions are related to but do not answer my question:

- [How to use scriptlets in HTMLOutput in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510858/how-to-use-scriptlets-in-htmloutput-in-google-apps-script)
- [Import sheet data into an include file using Google Apps Scriptlets in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61408067/import-sheet-data-into-an-include-file-using-google-apps-scriptlets-in-google-sh)
- [Including additional content file not working -  tags rendering as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039187/including-additional-content-file-not-working-tags-rendering-as-text)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use scriptlets in HTMLOutput in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510858/how-to-use-scriptlets-in-htmloutput-in-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster, that page is closely related to, though not exactly the same as, my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Apps Script scriptlets are being evaluated only once, at the beginning of script execution

In your case it makes more sense to use [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) that allows calling an Apps Script function from the client side (html file)

Sample:

`includedPage`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <script>
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateDiv).withUserObject(this).getServerData();
    function updateDiv(returnValue){
      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML="<p>"+ returnValue +"</p>"
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`Code.gs`

```
function getServerData() {
  var serverData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  return serverData[1];
}
```

Comment: Success! With this new tool, I can split up a complex page into multiple smaller pages, each of which can be made with data from the server (for a form or a table, etc), before everything gets assembled into the final layout. Thanks @ziganotschka